# Webservice to collect and to share photos organized in one album

Tags: gratis, web-apps, photography

I am looking for a webservice that I can use to collect and to share all pictures that my friends and me took on a holiday trip. Please name the best webservice you know to fulfill my needs (see requirements below).

## Requirements

It shall meet the following reqiurements:

### Must

1. Web service (no downloads, installations etc.)
2. Free service
3. Private link to upload
4. Non public uploads/private sharing of uploads
5. Anonymous upload without login
6. Allow files up to 5 MB
7. Storage limit greater than 3 GB

### Should

1. Easy upload (e.g. drag&drop)
2. Allow files up to 10 MB
3. Storage limit greater than 5 GB
4. View pictures online as photo gallery

Comment: Any requirements regarding the presentation of the uploaded files? Is it okay to just have a list of links, or do you need a gallery? // Viewing uploaded pictures should be possible for everyone, or only via private link? (same as the upload link?)

Comment: Thanks for you questions, I will clarify this by editing the question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending software, not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel nothing will ever be "completed". We also discussed that topic in chat back then. In brief: plain hosting/service questions *are* considered OT. Web-Apps are OK. And yes, there's a gray zone – but this one clearly is asking for a service, not for software. Seeing the answers on the linked meta question gives a clear vote on that.

Comment: This should not be closed. "Anonymous upload without login" is a distinctive enough feature, that it is special software.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know of any service that meets all of your requirements at once. But you could try to go with [EntourageBox](https://www.entouragebox.com/) in combination with either

- S3 Bucket
- Dropbox
- Google Drive

Not all of your requirements are met. Either way you have to limit yourself to 1 MB per uploaded file and 100 MB upload limit in total. Or you have to pay a *one time fee* of EUR 1.99 to enlarge limits to 500 MB per file and 5 GB in total.

Have a look at a screenshot of how EntourageBox works:

[image: Screenshot EntourageBox]

### Meets your requirements

1. Web service (no downloads, installations etc.) [image: full]
   **covered by Google Drive and EntourageBox**
2. Free service [image: partly]
   **both basically free; EntourageBox EUR 1.99 on time fee to enable large uploads and to enlarge limit; Google Drive 15 GB, monthly fees to enlarge limit**
3. Private link to upload [image: full]
   **covered by EntourageBox**
4. Non public uploads/private sharing of uploads [image: full]
   **covered by Google Drive**
5. Anonymous upload without login [image: full]
   **covered by EntourageBox, upload can even be protected with password**
6. Allow files up to 5 MB [image: partly]
   **EntourageBox 1 MB free, 100 MB one time fee - see above**
7. Storage limit greater than 3 GB [image: partly]
   **EntourageBox 100 MB free, 5 GB one time fee - see above; Google Drive 15 GB free, monthly fees to enlarge limit**
8. Easy upload (e.g. drag&drop) [image: full]
   **covered by EntourageBox**
9. View pictures online as photo gallery [image: full]
   **covered by Google Drive**

Comment: This seems like an interesting service, but it no longer exists. Do you maybe know of another service that matches the functionality?